# Passar xml como parâmetro para uma proc está retornando null

Tags: c#, oracle

O meu xml pode estar errado, claro. mas como eu não tenho certeza, digo: Preciso passar um parâmtero via programação para uma proc. Como no meu programa está vindo null, resolvi executar primeiro manualmente direto no pl/sql e continua não vindo nada. O xml montado pelo sistema vem assim:

```
    [0]: {<sCodPrestadorTs>1366348</sCodPrestadorTs>
}
    [1]: {<sCodPrestadorTsSub>3850055</sCodPrestadorTsSub>
}
    [2]: {<sCodRede>801</sCodRede>
}
    [3]: {<sCodOperadora>1</sCodOperadora>
}
    [4]: {<sDataExclusao>07/01/2016</sDataExclusao>
}
```

Para passar na mão, fiz assim:

```
<sCodPrestadorTs>1366348</sCodPrestadorTs>
<sCodPrestadorTsSub>3850055</sCodPrestadorTsSub>
<sCodRede>801</sCodRede>
<sCodOperadora>1</sCodOperadora>
<sDataExclusao>07/01/2016</sDataExclusao>
```

E assim eu passo na proc direto. O type passei para string, como pode ser visto na imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está errado nessa abordagem? Usei a tag c#, pois a aplicação onde o parâmetro é passado é em c#(web forms).

Um dos erros é que não havia uma tag pai. Coloquei e consegui rodar a proc e retornar alguma coisa. Ficou assim o xml:

```
<parametros>
    <sCodPrestadorTs>1366348</sCodPrestadorTs>
    <sCodPrestadorTsSub>3850055</sCodPrestadorTsSub>
    <sCodRede>801</sCodRede>
    <sCodOperadora>1</sCodOperadora>
    <sDataExclusao>07/01/2016</sDataExclusao>
</parametros>
```

Comment: É difícil saber qual o motivo de estar retornando `null`, pode ser problema no processo. Entretanto recomendo extremamente que, quando for trabalhar com `XML` em um banco de dados Oracle utilize o `XMLTYPE` ao invés de uma `STRING`. Se puder colocar o código da proc, poderá ser mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Descobri algumas coisas e já resolvi a questão do null. `1) deveria ter uma tag pai e não tinha 2) Eu estava passando um valor errado, em verdade estava errado, pois estavam fazendo manu no BD e esse BD de Dev. é usado por RJ e SP.` Esses eram os problemas do null, mas ainda não está resolvido. Não funciona da aplicação, apenas local no BD.